# Jenkins : how to print the contents of a text file to the build log?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a non-deterministically working Jenkins build step that prints text. It's multi line and has lots of urls in it. It's a python build step.

`print("""\
xxxx
yyy
")`

It works many times, but not all the times - it messes up the next step when it fails.

I'm not sure how to debug, but maybe I should just add a step that displays the contents of a text file on the console output log. I can't find such a plugin? 
thank you!

Comment: What do you mean it messes up the next step when it fails? The next step does not execute?

Comment: There are three steps; 1.The above HereDoc in python, which prints out; 2.A simple python print statement of one line, which prints; 3.The next 'real' code, also python, (all on windows 7) doing an import and call an api, fails with : "SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Build step 'Execute Python script' marked build as failure". When I run [3] on its own it is fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your Jenkins is running on Linux, a simple "Execute Shell" build-step with `cat filename.txt` will print the file to console

If running Windows, an "Execute Windows batch command" build-step with `type filename.txt` will do the same.

The filename path is relative to `WORKSPACE`